# Error:(3, 17) java: package org.junit does not exist- intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I recently started using IntelliJ to build my android application project. I imported my sherlock library as a module and added the dependency to my project. However when I try to rebuild my project to check any errors I get a lines of 10 errors like this:

```
Error:(3, 17) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(4, 24) java: package org.junit.runner does not exist
Error:(5, 23) java: package org.robolectric does not exist
Error:(7, 38) java: package org.fest.assertions.api does not exist
Error:(7, 1) java: static import only from classes and interfaces
Error:(9, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class RunWith
Error:(11, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ResourcesCompatTest
Error:(13, 20) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method cleanActivityName(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  location: class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ResourcesCompatTest
Error:(15, 20) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method cleanActivityName(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  location: class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ResourcesCompatTest
Error:(17, 19) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method cleanActivityName(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  location: class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ResourcesCompatTest
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

looks like the `junit.jar` is missing in your classpath. Add it and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

you can check if the plugin is installed if it is. it is just matter of adding it to class path you can do it automatically by  selecting the junit word and then press on the inspection left side yellow bulb choose "add junit to classpath"

Answer (score 0):

Adding below line in build.gradle solved the problem...

compile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'